# How to get key and key's children value with JSON.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, json.net

I'm trying to convert a json into a flat file for a database.
In order to do that, i have to pick up some value in the root node, then a key in a specific children, then each of the key's children value.

It turns out to be a nightmare with the `for each` and cast issue between `JObject`,`JToken` and `JProperty`

The source JSON

```
{
  "id": "030010014B",
  "type": "street",
  "housenumbers": {
    "13": {
      "lat": 46.085617,
      "lon": 3.460492
    },
    "1bis": {
      "lat": 46.08686,
      "lon": 3.459992
    },
    "5": {
      "lat": 46.086469,
      "lon": 3.460912
    }
  }
}
```

The expected result

```
// <id value>;<key of housenumber #>;<lon value>;<lat value>
030010014B;13;3.460492;46.085617
030010014B;1bis;3.459992;46.08686
030010014B;5;3.460912;46.086469
```

Current code that fails miserabily

```
Dim tmpJson As JObject = JObject.Parse(<json sample as string>)
Dim house As JToken
Dim house_p As JToken
If tmpJson.Property("housenumbers") IsNot Nothing Then
For Each houses As JObject In tmpJson.Property("housenumbers").Children 'only one
    For Each house In houses.Descendants
        fs.Append(tmpJson.Property("id").Value.ToString & ";")
        Dim hh As JProperty = house 'failing here
        fs.Append(hh.Name & ";") 'no way to get a key without jproperty 
        For Each house_p In house.Children()
            fs.AppendLine(house_p.Value(Of String)("lon") & ";" & house_p.Value(Of String)("lat"))
        Next
    Next
Next
End If
...
```

My failing example is inspired from the C# answers around SO but the "value to keys to values" seems rather rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get them as a collection of objects and iterate that:

```
Public Class Location
    <JsonProperty("lat")>
    Public Property Latitude As Single
    <JsonProperty("lon")>
    Public Property Longitude As Single
End Class
```

Then deserialize the inner part into sa Dictionary:

```
Dim jstr = from whereever
Dim jobj = JObject.Parse(jstr)

Dim id As String = jobj("id").ToString

Dim numbers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Location))(jobj("housenumbers").ToString())

For Each kvp In numbers
    Console.WriteLine("key:{0}, lat: {1}, long: {2}",
                      kvp.Key, kvp.Value.Latitude,
                      kvp.Value.Longitude)
Next
```

> key:13, lat: 46.08562, long: 3.460492
>   key:1bis, lat: 46.08686, long: 3.459992
>   key:5, lat: 46.08647, long: 3.460912

The `030010014B` would be in your Id variable

Comment: I do not really understand what happens but it works ! What would be the type of `numbers` if I wanted to declare it before using it ? `numbers As Dictionary(Of String,Location)` doesnt work

Comment: You can declare it as a Dictionary elsewhere, but you still need `Of Dictionary(Of String, Location)` in the  `DeserializeObject` method - that tells Json.NET what form to deserialize it to.